# Read values from database into Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read from the database and place the values into an array of strings. However, when I try to push the values into an array then print the array the app crashes.

```
var pets: [String]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("pets")
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let snap = snapshot.value as? Bool {
            print("no values")
        } else if let snap = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            for value in snap {
                print(value.key as! String)    // Prints out data in the database
                self.pets?.append(value.key as! String)
            }
            print(self.pets!)

        }
    })
```

Does anybody know why the `print(value.key as! String)` prints out the data but then when I print out the array the app crashes with `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize `pets`. You declare it as an optional but never assign it a value. Why not change your code to the following:

```
var pets = [String]() // start with an empty array 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("pets")
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let snap = snapshot.value as? Bool {
            print("no values")
        } else if let snap = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            for value in snap {
                print(value.key as! String)    // Prints out data in the database
                self.pets.append(value.key as! String)
            }
            print(self.pets)

        }
    })
```

Comment: FYI - I strongly urge you to spend some quality time reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu?s=1|6.4447

Answer (score 1):

Your array is `nil` when you try to *force-unwrapping* using:

```
print(self.pets!)
```

As you are using `self.pets?.append()` you don't have any problem because you are using the chaining of optionals, but your array, in fact, is `nil` at that time because you forgot to initialize it before use it. If you instead use `self.pets!.append()` you will see a runtime error instead.

So as @rmaddy suggest you can initialize the array at the beginning or just inside your `viewDidLoad()` it's up to you.

I hope this help you.